# How to get metric data for azure cloud service?

Tags: azure

I am working in cloud service api and want to read metric data for cloud service.
Since the cloud insight api do not support the provider namespace 'Microsoft.ClassicCompute'

Is there any other way to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

The metrics can be obtained by using azure InsightsClient.

Comment: It would certainly help others if you can elaborate on your answer. May be share some code that you end up writing/using to fetch this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get basic "external" metrics (CPU/Network In/Out) via the InsightsClient.  The overall infrastructure of getting metrics from Azure is moving to newly released Metrics API and only a few resources are supported thru this API at the moment.

The best way to get at the detailed metrics from Cloud Services is to utilize Azure Table Storage and look for WADPerformanceCounters table that's created by the Azure Diagnostics Extension (or Azure Diagnostics Module if you're in pre-SDK 2.5).  This table will contain all of the performance counter values from all instances in the monitored Cloud Roles.

Alternatively, you could utilize a 3rd party tool, like [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com), to get pretty dashboards, alerts, automation, etc for Cloud Services and other Azure resources (note: I'm affiliated with CloudMonix)

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned above you can get the metric data from Insight Client.

For this you need to first get the deployment slot on which you want monitoring data.
Below is the sample url for getting deployement slot.

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{CloudServiceName}/slots/Production/roles?api-version=2014-01-01

Now you need to pass the slot to the below url.

```
var url="/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{CloudServiceName}/slots/Production/roles/{deployement slot}/"
string start = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1).ToString(dateTimeFormat);;
            string end = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(dateTimeFormat);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(filter);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            {
                sb.Append(" and ");
            }
            sb.AppendFormat("startTime eq {0} and endTime eq {1}", start, end);
            sb.AppendFormat(" and timeGrain eq duration'{0}'", duration);
            using (var client = new InsightsClient(credentials))
            {
                    return client.MetricOperations.GetMetrics(url, sb.ToString()); 
            }
```